# Loading an Assembly fails because of incorrect format

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies, x86, 64-bit

I develop on a pretty big windows forms .net (C#) application with several assemblys. Originally each assembly was build for the Target Platfom "Any CPU". 
Due to a problem with Crystal Reports on x64 machines we had to build the whole project for x86 target platform. I startet rebuilding some of our Projects for x86 and it worked just fine. 
But with one I have the problem that when I try to use it as a reference in another Assembly, the other one won't load it giving following Error:

> Could not load file or assembly #MyAssembly# or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

When playing Around with Crystal in a sample project with more than one assembly I found out that this error occurs when the Projects are build for different target platforms. But this isn't the case here. I build every Project for X86 and just can't figure out where the problem is here.

Comment: Have you checked the task manager if your application is actually running in 32bit mode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try, to build your MainProject (Executable) with target platform "x86" or "x64", an all other projects you set to "Any CPU".

Comment: Yeah this doesn't work. It seems like that including Assemblys built for x86 can't be included in applications built for any CPU. (At least this was my experience)

Comment: @Robert Spari: Only your MainProject (WindowsForms) with the Main-Methode should be compiled with "x86". All other projects (Library) should be compiled with "Any CPU".

Comment: I'm sorry you were absolutely right I just handed it over for testing. Thanks a lot

Comment: This worked. Possibly related to: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/06/19/resgen-exe-error-an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-an-incorrect-format.aspx