# Metricam: Could not load file or Assembly: Webcam.dll

Tags: c#, .net, x86, 64-bit, webcam

We are experiencing a problem with the Metricam library.
The Metricam documentation states:

> Your application platform target has to be “x86″. “AnyCPU” and “x64″
>   is currently not working because not all camera manufacturers supply
>   64-bit drivers / APIs. However, we are working on a 64-bit version of
>   MetriCam. 
>   .NET 2.0 compatibility: If you have a .NET 4.0 project,
>   please add the following line to your app.config: `<startup
>   useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy=”true” > </startup>`

We have followed this instructions, and when we run our system, a small test app, on x64 it works fine, but when we run it on x86 we get a message saying

> Could not load file or assembly: WebCam.dll

We are using .NET 4.0, and compile with Any CPU (attempting to compile with x86 fails due to other library dependencies).

The required .dll's are in the bin folder, and as I said, running this app works fine on x64.

At this stage we feel totally lost and out of ideas, so if anyone could help us, we would greatly appreciate it!

Thanks!

EDIT: We've now managed to compile in x86, to no avail. We have also discovered that the problem is in the Metricam.dll which is 32 bit. No closer to a solution though...

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in that you compile the assembly in "AnyCPU" and not "x86" as they require.
It is not possibly to make a program work with both 64 and 32 bit at the same time. =(

Edit:
Not that it helps a lot, but here's an answer from Microsoft about the differences:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshwil/archive/2005/04/08/406567.aspx

If the assemblies (DLLs) you are loading to the project would use AnyCPU it seems it would be a lot easier for you though.

Comment: Hi, We have just tried compiling with all as x86, and with the main as x86 and the rest as Any CPU as suggested here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049517/loading-an-assembly-fails-because-of-incorrect-format). None of this helped. :(

Comment: "Any CPU" will be executed as 64 bit on a 64 bit processor and as 32 bit on a 32 bit processor. So, if you are running the program on a 64 bit processor as "Any CPU", it will be executed as 64 bit, and any 32-bit library included will result with an error.

Comment: We discovered that the problem was the (ancient) test pc. It works everywhere else. Problem solved! :-)

Answer (score 0):

please make sure to install Visual C++ Redistributable 2012 (x86) (select VSU4\vcredist_x86.exe in the download window):

http://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=30679

Christian

Comment: We discovered what our problem was three weeks ago, as commented on the other answer.